# Logging xml content in http request

Tags: c, gsoap

Currently I am working on an application and need to log all the xml content in http request/response. My application is based on C and use gsoap. I have very less experience on working with gsoap. 
Went through the gsoap userguide also some answers on stackoverflow which suggests to use plugins and refer to plugin.h and plugin.c files. I went through all of them but was not able to understand how to proceed.

This is needed for both http and https request/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the message logging plugin declared in `gsoap/plugin/logging.h` as follows:

```
#include "plugin/logging.h"

struct soap *ctx = soap_new();

// Register the plugin
soap_register_plugin(ctx, logging);

// Change logging destinations to stdout (or another open FILE*):
soap_set_logging_inbound(ctx, stdout);
soap_set_logging_outbound(ctx, stdout);
...
```

Then compile your code together with `gsoap/plugin/logging.c`.